# receive an error when pushing node.js app on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, hosting

when i try to upload my node.js app onto heroku i get this error

```
 -----> Node.js app detected
remote: parse error: Unfinished JSON term
remote:  !     Unable to parse package.json
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote: parse error: Unfinished JSON term
remote: parse error: Unfinished JSON term
remote:
```

can anyone tell me how to get past this? here is the package.JSON file

```
{
"name": "myapp",
"version": "1.0.0",


"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node index.js",
"engines": {
"node": ">=50.9" 
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.16.2",
"twilio": "^3.9.3"
}



}
```

thank you

Comment: You need to post your package.json here. You probably have a syntax error there.

Comment: sorry about tha. I've added it now

Comment: Your "node" version looks suspicious: ">=50.9" ?? Maybe you meant 5.9?

Comment: i changed it to 8.5.0 still doesn't work. sorry I've been trying to get this to work for 4 hours now

Answer (score 0):

Close your "scripts" entry after "start":

```
{
 "name": "myapp",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
 },
 "engines": {
   "node": ">=5.9" 
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "twilio": "^3.9.3"
 }

}
```

Comment: thanks! now when i run push heroku master i get this long error "npm ERR! /tmp/build_a0faeb77bf9f3de27aa308181810d990/node_modules/sshpk/binsshpk-conv" it also says a possible problem is nodes_module checked into source control.

Comment: Put node_modules in your .gitignore.